# Invalid data still emits "child_added" events?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
const uid = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
const itemId = Firebase.database().ref('user_items/' +uid+ '/items').push().key    

Firebase.database().ref('user_items/' +uid+ '/items/' +itemId)
.set({
  BUTTS: Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

I have validation rules that shouldn't allow "BUTTS" as a key. When I run the piece of code below I get an error in `console` (as expected)... but my `child_added` listener still emits with that *gluteus maximalistic* new data.

Is this expected behavior? Should I be listening to a different event?

---

EDIT: Adding my rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "user_items": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user",
        "items": {
          "$item": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['a', 'foo'])",
            "$other": {
              ".validate": "false"
            },
            ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
            ".write": "auth.uid === $user",
            "a": {
              ".validate": "newData.isString()"
            },
            "foo": {
              ".validate": "newData.isString()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your security rules.

Comment: @BobSnyder added

Comment: I'll leave this for Frank or another Firebaser to answer (it's the end of the day for me).  This issue has probably been raised before and answered on SO but I couldn't find it.  Based on my experiments, I would say this is the expected behavior.  If you expand your listener to include `child_removed` events, you will find that when the write is rejected, you get a `child_added` event for each child, followed by a `child_removed` for each, so the change is effectively nullified.  Your code needs to listen for both events and handle appropriately.

Comment: @BobSnyder: I indeed answered this a few times, but can't find it either. Can you include the contents of your comment into your answer? Without that it's a link-only answer, which typically get closed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Done

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks guys. Loving the convenience of Firebase... I would expect the validation to prevent the "child_added" event from ever happening... just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.  It's all explained in this [Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html).

Permissions are enforced on the server, not the client.  To improve responsiveness, the listeners fire immediately when a change is detected in the client.  If the change is rejected by the server, the client is notified and listener events are fired to reverse the change.  This is summarized at the end of the blog post:

> When there is an update to a location that also has active listeners
>   in the same process, the flow of data through the process goes like
>   this:
>
> 1. Immediately call all relevant listeners with the new value
> 2. Send the update to the Firebase server side
> 3. Check security rules for validity
> 4. If a security rule was violated, notify the client SDK
> 5. Roll back the change in the app by calling relevant listeners again to back to the original state

You will need to listen for both `child_added` and `child_removed` events and respond as needed to handle permission failures.

Comment: Thanks again @BobSynder. I would suggest Firebase remove the client-side immediate updating. It makes handling app state (slightly) more sophisticated since I have to wait a few seconds to ensure that there isn't a "child_removed" event

Comment: Thanks for the help and your work with Firebase. It's a great product.

Comment: Actually... I see what you guys are trying to do. It seems this "confusion" is in the name of facilitating the offline experience... I would suggest that you rename the events from "child_added" to "new_child_queued". The former name implies that the the child was actually added to the database. Which it's not.