# Firebase 'value' event triggered even though the write operation was disallowed due to a security rule

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an `alarms` branch in my firebase database which allows write if the resulting alarm contains some fields or the alarm is deleted. The security rules looks like below

```
    "alarms": {
        "$alarmId": {
          ".write": "auth !== null && (newData.hasChildren(['id', 'name', 'date', 'status']) || !newData.exists())"
        },
        ".indexOn": "name"
    }
```

Without going into much detail about the actual workflow, in some cases, I may delete the alarm and then try to perform some update right after the delete finishes. This is done when processing some operations that were queued up while the user was offline. The update that is performed after the delete shouldn't be allowed because the resulting data wouldn't contain the required field as mentioned in the `write` rule. Below is a piece of code that simulates what I do

```
      GlobalConfig.rootFirebaseRef.child('alarms').child('test').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.tron.log('Detected a change at test alarm ' + JSON.stringify(snapshot.val() || {}))
      })
      GlobalConfig.rootFirebaseRef.child('alarms').child('test').set({name: 'blah', id: 'blah', status: true, date: Date.now()}).then(() => {
        console.tron.log('Finished set')
        let firebaseUpdate = {}
        firebaseUpdate['alarms/test'] = null;
        return GlobalConfig.rootFirebaseRef.update(firebaseUpdate)
      }).then(() => {
        console.tron.log('Finished delete')
        let firebaseUpdateObj = {}
        const currDate = Date.now()
        firebaseUpdateObj['alarms/' + 'test' + '/lastSnoozeByCreatorOn'] = currDate
        firebaseUpdateObj['alarms/' + 'test' + '/lastSnoozeByCreatorFor'] = 120
        firebaseUpdateObj['alarms/' + 'test' + '/lastUpdatedAt'] = currDate
        return GlobalConfig.rootFirebaseRef.update(firebaseUpdateObj)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.tron.log('push error ' + JSON.stringify(error))
      })
```

As you can see, I am pushing a new dummy alarm, then deleting it and then performing a partial update. Below are the console log statements.

```
Detected a change at test alarm {"date":1499488553686,"id":"blah","name":"blah","status":true}
Finished set
Detected a change at test alarm {}
Finished delete
Detected a change at test alarm {"lastSnoozeByCreatorFor":120,"lastSnoozeByCreatorOn":1499488556766,"lastUpdatedAt":1499488556766}
FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied 
Detected a change at test alarm {}
push error {"line":68548,"column":89,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false","code":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}
```

As evident from the console logs, the write after delete was disallowed but the `value` event handler was still triggered with the partial update.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: When there is a permission failure, the listeners fire with the initial update and then again when the update is rejected.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700615/4815718 and this [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html).

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder. I little unexpected for a new user but I understand the motivation behind it after reading the blog post.